# what changes do the app go during upgrade from market in android

Tags: android

I am looking for information about the upgrade process in android. I mean I want to know if the application is reinstalled? Is the cache cleared? Is the external storage folders deleted (as these are deleted during uninstall)? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, no, nothing changes except for the apk.  This includes `res/` and `assets/`, but will not include anything stored to the device's `/sdcard/data/` directory.

If there is a sql lite database, it should be associated with a version number.  If the db has to change in an upgrade, it is the developer's responsibility to implement a database upgrade for existing database, within their new release.

Keep in mind if the developer wants to, they can delete external resources.  But natively, no Android will leave folders in `/sdcard/data/` or whereever they might be stored.

Also, yes, the cache is cleared.  This is actually from uninstalling the older version before reinstalling the new one.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather here: http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/android-market/technical-help/0y8wNUhZEWo

It only replaces the .apk file.